# Cambiar la etiqueta [no-sql] por [nosql]

Tags: soporte

La siguiente pregunta: [Aplicar filtros a consulta NoSQL en MongoDB](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/894/aplicar-filtros-a-consulta-nosql-en-mongodb) está etiquetada como [no-sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/no-sql), sin embargo el término correcto debría ser [nosql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nosql)

Sin embargo al tratar de editar la etiqueta me sale el siguiente mensaje de error:

> No se pudieron enviar tus etiquetas. Consulta el error que se indica más arriba.

[image: Error al editar etiqueta]

¿Es posible que algún moderador o dev nos ayude a hacer esta edición?

Y de paso agregar [no-sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/no-sql) como un sinónimo de [nosql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nosql)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He agregado la etiqueta [nosql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nosql) como sinónimo de [no-sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/no-sql).

Comment: Juan en realidad lo que necesitamos es que sea al revés. [tag:no-sql] > [tag:nosql]

Comment: El orden ha sido corregido.